# Add data to Bash array over multiple scripts

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, scripting

I need to pass array data between two bash scripts.

I have a controller configuration which both scripts source (etc/config). In this file I have three arrays declared:

```
declare -a exeSuccess
declare -a exeFailure
declare -a exeUnknown
```

My master script calls various subscripts in parallel which gather data and output to the array.

Subscript:

```
exeSuccess+=($OUTPUT) #This works while the script is running
```

Master Script:

```
for z in $(ls -l scripts)
do
  sh $z &
  wait
done

echo "Validating Script Output"
echo ${exeSuccess[@]}
```

While the scripts are running, the array is populated as needed, but when they exit, the array is emptied (I am assuming destroyed).

Does anyone know how I can keep this array initialised over the execution of the master script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays are not shared between the different shells. Each script will run as a separate process, and build its own private arrays, but these are lost when the process exits. @Upasana Shukla's suggestion of running the scripts with `source` will work (because it runs them in the main shell process, rather than as subshells/diferent processes), but will not allow you to run the scripts in parallel.  If you want to run them in parallel, the simplest way is probably to have them output to temporary files instead of arrays:

```
export tmpdir="$(mktemp -d "/tmp/$(basename "$0").XXXXXX")" || {
    echo "Error creating temporary directory" >&2
    exit 1
}

for z in scripts/*; do # Please don't parse ls
   sh "$z" &
done
wait

echo "Validating Script Output"
cat "$tmpdir/exeSuccess"
rm -R "$tmpdir"
```

And in the individual scripts:

```
echo "$OUTPUT" >>"$tmpdir/exeSuccess"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script, you're creating a subshell by doing sh $z, replace sh with source, like this:

```
source scriptname.sh
```

in this way, your script will not create a subshell and variables which you define in your script will exists even after termination of your script.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script.sh

source script2.sh;
echo ${exeSuccess[0]};
echo ${exeSuccess[1]};


#!/bin/bash
#scipt2.sh
declare -a exeSuccess;
exeSuccess[0]="hello";
exeSuccess[1]="hello1";
```

Output:

```
$ source script1.sh
hello
hello1
$ echo ${exeSuccess[0]}
hello
$ echo ${exeSuccess[1]}
hello1
$
```